# How do I get ONLY the validated data from a laravel FormRequest?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request-validation

Lets say I have the following Custom Request:

```
class PlanRequest extends FormRequest
{
    // ...


    public function rules()
    {

        return
        [
            'name'              => 'required|string|min:3|max:191',
            'monthly_fee'       => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'transaction_fee'   => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'processing_fee'    => 'required|numeric|min:0|max:100',
            'annual_fee'        => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'setup_fee'         => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'organization_id'   => 'exists:organizations,id',
        ];
    }
}
```

When I access it from the controller, if I do `$request->all()`, it gives me **ALL** the data, including extra garbage data that isn't meant to be passed.

```
public function store(PlanRequest $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
    // This returns
    [
        'name'              => 'value',
        'monthly_fee'       => '1.23',
        'transaction_fee'   => '1.23',
        'processing_fee'    => '1.23',
        'annual_fee'        => '1.23',
        'setup_fee'         => '1.23',
        'organization_id'   => null,
        'foo'               => 'bar', // This is not supposed to show up
    ];
}
```

How do I get **ONLY** the validated data without manually doing `$request->only('name','monthly_fee', etc...)`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

#### [`$request->validated()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation) will return only the validated data.

**Example:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    $validatedData = $request->validated();

}
```

---

#### Alternate Solution:

`$request->validate([rules...])` returns the only validated data if the validation passes.

**Example:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

}
```

Comment: I figured this out, but I'm going to upvote yours cuz you beat me to the punch. :)

Comment: There should be a way to do the same without FormRequest

Comment: Lravel 9
$validated = $request->safe();

Answer (score 9):

OK... After I spent the time to type this question out, I figured I'd check the laravel "API" documentation: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html

Looks like I can use `$request->validated()`. Wish they would say this in the Validation documentation. It makes my controller actions look pretty slick:

```
public function store(PlanRequest $request)
{
    return response()->json(['plan' => Plan::create($request->validated())]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be an old thread and some people might have used the `Validator` class instead of using the `validator()` helper function for request.

To those who fell under the latter category, you can use the `validated()` function to retrieve the array of validated values from request.

```php
$validator = Validator::make($req->all(), [
    // VALIDATION RULES
], [
    // VALIDATION MESSAGE
]);

dd($validator->validated());
```

This returns an array of all the values that passed the validation.

This only starts appearing in the docs since [Laravel 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#clipText-9) but it might work up to Laravel 5.2