# Laravel - request validation

Tags: laravel, validation

I extedned request class to create my own valdiation rules. In that class I added my custom validation function. In function I check if tags are pass regEx and I would like to filter tags to remove tags shorter then 2 characters.

And later keep in request only tags that passed validation.

```
    public function createPost(PostRequest $request)
{
    dd($request->all()); //In this place I would like to keep only tags passed through validation not all tags recived in request
}
```

Is it possibile to do it? How to set it in Request class?

```
'tags' => [
            'nullable',
            'string',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail){
                $tagsArray = explode(',', $value);
                if(count($tagsArray) > 5) {
                    $fail(__('place.tags_max_limit'));
                }

                $tagsFiltered = [];
                foreach ($tagsArray as $tag){
                    $tag = trim($tag);
                    if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/',$tag)){
                        $tagsFiltered[] = $tag;
                    };
                }

                return $tagsFiltered;
            }
        ],
```

EDIT:
I think we miss understanding. I would like to after validation have only tags that returned in variable `$tagsFiltered;` Not the same as recived in input.

Comment: You have to create a custom rule with `php artisan make:rule`, use the class in the controller, and then just instanciate it into `validate()` function.

Comment: `$request->validated()`  ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936337/how-do-i-get-only-the-validated-data-from-a-laravel-formrequest

Comment: I've posted a more complete answer below. See if it helps, please.

Comment: @LucasArbex tho OP is using a [form request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validationt)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Oh yeah, how dumb I am. I will make another answer below then.

Comment: @LucasArbex don't worry, just fix your answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to create this custom regex rule and use it into `rules()` function.

Like so:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'tag' => 'regex:/[^]{2,}/'
    ];
}

public function createPost(PostRequest $request)
{
    $request->validated();
}
```

And then just call it via `validated()` function wherever you want.

Comment: I updated my question. In your example I still get the same result.

Answer (score -1):

first define validation rule with this command:

```
php artisan make:rule TagsFilter
```

navigate to TagsFilter rule file and define your filter on passes method:

```
   public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
                $tagsArray = explode(',', $value);
                $tagsFiltered = [];
                foreach ($tagsArray as $tag){
                    $tag = trim($tag);
                    if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/',$tag)){
                        $tagsFiltered[] = $tag;
                    };
                }

        return count($tagsArray) > 5 && count($tagsFiltered) > 0;
    }
```

then include your rule in your validation on controller:

```
$request->validate([
    'tags' => ['required', new TagsFilter],
]);
```