# How to remove null values from array for validation in Laravel JSON column

Tags: laravel, validation

In a Laravel model, I am using a JSON column `data` to store custom data.  The JSON data can be nested for organization, and all keys should have non-empty/non-null values.

At the moment all keys are hard-coded in the form as `data[key]` on the frontend.  If a `key` previously stored has its `value` blanked out on the frontend, `key` should be unset in the update method.  However, upon validation, I'm getting the original array back.

```php
// ModelController.php
public function update(Request $request, Model $model)
{
    // $request->data = ['key' => null, 'nested' => ['key' => null]]

    function stripEmptyCustom($data) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($data[$key])){
                $data[$key] = stripEmptyCustom($data[$key]);
            }

            if (empty($value)){
                unset($data[$key]);
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }

    $request->data = stripEmptyCustom($request->data);

    dump($request->data);                   // so far, so good
                                            // $request->data = []

    $attributes = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'nullable',
        'data' => 'array',
    ]);

    dump($attributes);                      // $attributes['data'] =
                                            // ['key' => null, 'nested' => ['key' => null]]
```

How do I validate the request without it resetting the original data?

Comment: [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) can be used to remove keys with a null/empty value.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I read that too, however `$data = array_filter($request->data)` was leaving the keys in there.  as was `array_filter($request->data, 'array_filter')`

Comment: Something else is likely off then, I've used it before this exact purpose. As stated by the docs: `If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.`

Comment: there's that too.  but since my code up to that point demonstrably works, I'm leaning towards the issue being within the `$request` itself.  like you know how there's an `original` array and an `attributes` array within each model?  wondering if my update changes one, but the other's being validated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to only return the validated data, and not the whole data response. The validation method will continue the controller normally if the validated data is correct, It might be doing another request in there somewhere.

what I think you are looking for is to only return the data that **is** valid:

using something like: `$request->validated();` hopefully will solve your issue:

Im referencing these resources:
[How do I get ONLY the validated data from a laravel FormRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936337/how-do-i-get-only-the-validated-data-from-a-laravel-formrequest)

validation docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround in stripping the nulls **after** validation:

```php
function stripEmptyCustom($data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($data[$key])){
            $data[$key] = stripEmptyCustom($data[$key]);
        }

        if (empty($value)){
            unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

$attributes = $request->validate([
    'name' => 'nullable',
    'data' => 'array',
]);

$attributes = stripEmptyCustom($attributes);
```